# Iterating Recursively Through Object

Tags: c#

I have an object that contains objects and other types with one of them being a boolean for its active status. What I am wanting to do is iterate over the object and its properties to check the boolean for each property object that contains this boolean. This is what I have so far:

```
    public void checkStatus(object Object, string property)
    {
        Type objectType = Object.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] propertiesInfo = objectType.GetProperties();
        foreach (var item in propertiesInfo) {
            if (item.Name == property && (Boolean)item.GetValue(Object) == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item + " is active");
                checkStatus((object)item, property);
            }
            else if (item.Name == property && (Boolean)item.GetValue(Object) != true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item + " is not active.");
                checkStatus((object)item, property);
            }
            else {
                Console.WriteLine("Property does not exist in" + item);
            }
        }
    }
```

Only checks the first level and doesn't go any further. Ideas?

This is what it pulls with the first bit of data being wanted:

```
Boolean IsActive is active
Property does not exist inSystem.Reflection.MemberTypes MemberType
Property does not exist inSystem.String Name
Property does not exist inSystem.Type DeclaringType
Property does not exist inSystem.Type ReflectedType
Property does not exist inInt32 MetadataToken
Property does not exist inSystem.Reflection.Module Module
Property does not exist inSystem.Type PropertyType
Property does not exist inSystem.Reflection.PropertyAttributes Attributes
Property does not exist inBoolean CanRead
Property does not exist inBoolean CanWrite
Property does not exist inBoolean IsSpecialName
Property does not exist inSystem.Reflection.MethodInfo GetMethod
Property does not exist inSystem.Reflection.MethodInfo SetMethod
Property does not exist inSystem.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Reflection.CustomAttributeData] CustomAttributes
Property does not exist inSystem.Nullable`1[System.Int64] CardNumber
Property does not exist inConsoleApp1.Client Client
Property does not exist inConsoleApp1.Account Account
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same with a simple linq without recursion:

```
var activeProperties = objectType.GetProperties().Where(prop => prop.Name == property && (Boolean)item.GetValue(Object) == true);
```

The above will containt all active properties, you can do with them as you please.

recursion is slower, and takes up more of the stack as well. The main advantage of recursion is that for problems like tree traversal it make the algorithm a little easier or more "elegant" - which is nothing you do here.

Just use link and you can nest\drill into the object as deep as you need.

P.S.

instead of

```
(Boolean)item.GetValue(Object) != true
```

please use:

```
(Boolean)item.GetValue(Object) == false
```

You got me more confused then Bobby Lashley (if anyone is watching the botch guy here).

Comment: I appreciate your help, and I modified the code to this:

            var activeProperties = Object.GetType().GetProperties().Where(prop => prop.Name == property && (Boolean)prop.GetValue(Object) == true);
            foreach (var prop in activeProperties) {
                Console.WriteLine(prop);
                checkStatus(prop, property);
            }

...but it is still only pulling the first objects values.

Answer (score 0):

Your recursion logic is correct. The issue is rather that you are calling `checkStatus` on `item`, which is a `propertyInfo` object, not the property. Instead of calling `checkStatus` on `item`, call it on `item.GetValue(object)`.